# Verifying if one list contains a string from another list

Tags: java

I am trying to validate that when given two lists,

```
List<String> models;
List<String> titleOfVehicle;
```

that one of the `models` must be contained in each of the `titleOfVehicle`.

For example, given the following:

```
models = {Accord, Civic, Element}
titleOfVehicle1 = {2014 Honda Accord, 2011 Toyota Camry}
titleOfVehicle2 = {2013 Honda Accord, 2015 Honda Element, 2011 Honda Civic}
```

then when comparing `models` and `titleOfVehicle1` it will fail since `2011 Toyota Camry` does not contain one of the models provided. However, `titleOfVehicle2` will pass since it contains a model for each vehicle titles.

---

Here is my code:

```
public boolean compareTwoList(List<String> models, List<String> titleOfVehicles) {
    boolean flag = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < titleOfVehicles.size(); i++) {
        flag = false;
        int k = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < models.size(); j++) {
            if(titleOfVehicles.get(i).contains(models.get(j))) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            } else if(k == models.size() - 1 && flag == false) {                        
                return false;
            }    
            k++;
        }
    }    
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is more complicated than it needs to be, but it gets the job done.

The awkward part of your code is the use of the various index values `i`, `j`, and `k`. Really, you don't need them at all. If you rename things a bit, and use "enhanced-for" loops, it becomes:

```
public boolean compareTwoList(List<String> models, List<String> titleOfVehicles) {

    for(String title : titleOfVehicles) {
        boolean found = false;
        for(String model : models) {
            if(title.contains(model)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            return false;
        }
    }    
    return true;
}
```

Note that the logic is essentially the same, but you focus on the important things. The `found` variable is a better name, and it's scope is limited to inside the outer for-loop. The hard-to-understand `k` loop-terminator is removed.

Note, using streams, and a regular expression, would actually be more compact solution, but may not be as readable... I played with the stream version and a regex, and got:

```
public static boolean compareTwoList(List<String> models, List<String> titleOfVehicles) {

    String pattern = models.stream()
          .map(Pattern::quote)
          .collect(Collectors.joining("|", ".*(", ").*"));

    Pattern re = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    return titleOfVehicles.stream()
        .allMatch(t -> re.matcher(t).matches());

}
```

(which you can see working here: https://ideone.com/8sqKu7 )

Answer (score 5):

The current code works but it is very awkward, as [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl) [pointed out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/134931/95296). I would add that you should never compare booleans with `true` or `false`, like what you're doing in:

```
} else if(k == models.size() - 1 && flag == false) {                        
    return false;
}
```

Instead, have

```
} else if (k == models.size() - 1 && !flag) {                        
    return false;
}
```

---

You can actually accomplish this task in a single, clear and easy line using the Stream API:

```
public boolean compareTwoList(List<String> models, List<String> titleOfVehicles) {
    return titleOfVehicles.stream().allMatch(t -> models.stream().anyMatch(t::contains));
}
```

This does exactly what is written: it returns whether all elements in the given titles contains any of the given models.

Both [`allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) are short-circuiting operations, so it will behave exactly like your current code.